# How to use Countdown Timer in NativeScript?

Tags: angular2-nativescript

How can I Implement Countdown Timer with date format in NativeScript  ?

setInterval(() => {

}, 1000);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  getRemainingTime(remainingMillis) {
    setInterval(() => {
      let seconds = Math.floor(remainingMillis / 1000);
      let minute = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
      seconds = seconds % 60;
      let hour = Math.floor(minute / 60);
      minute = minute % 60;
      const day = Math.floor(hour / 24);
      hour = hour % 24;
      let remainTime
      if (day > 0) {
        remainTime = day + "d:" + hour + "h:" + minute + "m:" + seconds + "s";
      } else {
        remainTime = hour + "h:" + minute + "m:" + seconds + "s";
      }
      remainingMillis = remainingMillis - 1000;
      console.log(remainTime);
    }, 1000); 
  }
```

Comment: Should i pass in milliseconds as a parameter to the method?

Comment: @KhizarHussan.M.A - you can use a variable outside of the method (i.e., move remainingTime to the scope you need it)

Comment: @KhizarHussan.M.A -  yes , You have to pass Milliseconds .

Comment: @DanielM - Yeah got it buddy. Thanks a lot.